# Best Practice to Increase Frame Per Second for my daydream VR application

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, daydream

I am developing pretty details-simple VR application in Unity for Daydream platform, and because it is running on a phone the Frame Per Second (FPS) are extremely important to maintain 60.

What are the best practices to increase FPS and improve performance?

Comment: Have you taken a look at  https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/optimisation-vr-unity for VR optimisation,  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html for general graphics performance and https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileOptimizationPracticalGuide.html for mobile optimisation?

Comment: Thanks for the response, and yeah I took a look but because there are many ways to do so I thought to hear some ideas.

Comment: Well, this site is not a discussion site. Any answers you get here will just be the same thing the guide tells you how to do but in a less detailed way that will be harder to follow.

Comment: There are just too many possibilities right now on what could pose a performance problem and how you might address it. Implement your application, determine whether it fails to meet your performance standards, then use the Unity Profiler to identify the primary offenders in your application. Try to address them yourself (you may need to do some/much research for that). If you really can't figure it out, then consider writing a question on Stack Overflow about the specific problem you're trying to solve - until then, best of luck.

Comment: Try this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4YAY36xjwE
Your question needs to be much more specific. You cannot expect a good answer from such a general question.